# Models are reloaded on every request if any source file changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our Rails 5 application in development mode, all model classes are reloaded on every request if any of the source files has changed. So even if only model `A` changed, model `B` is reloaded as well. This leads to very slow request times as the DB schema is reloaded as well when a model is reloaded.

If I interpret the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) correctly, turning on `config.reload_classes_only_on_change = true` should prevent non-changed files from being reloaded. I didn't notice any difference though.

Why is this behavior and is there a way to change it and speed up the development mode?

Comment: have you did this   config.cache_classes = false

Comment: Yes: `config.cache_classes = false` and `config.eager_load = false`.

Comment: Rails reloads all the models since it ensures that any changes to the database schema is propogated to the models.